# implications of giving full read/write access to the user account (IIS 7.5/ASP.Net)

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, iis-7.5

Assuming the website is stored at `c:\websites\testing.com\`

Currently, the web application writes files to:

```
/uploads/
/robots.txt
/sitemap.xml
```

Rather than having to give permissions to each file, is it a security implication to just give read/write access to the whole `c:\websites\testing.com\` folder for the application pool user (e.g `IIS AppPool\testing`)?

What is the 'worst-case' that could happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how secure your application is. I'd pay particular attention to any [Path Traversal](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal) vulnerabilities. e.g. if it is possible for a user to upload a file passing the filename as "`../foo.aspx"`? You'd have to test this using an [intercepting proxy](http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html). If so it may be possible for them to write a file into your root folder.

This is one example of path traversal, it doesn't necessarily have to start with the double dots. If you are confident your application is secure there is minimal risk, but since there are only 3 files & folders in your case it may be better to apply the permissions individually.

Comment: So the main implication is that the website application has access to the entire folder (not anything beyond that).  So if there are any parts of the application which allow the user to access somehow files/folders which they shouldn't, they wouldn't be blocked by an `AccessNotAuthorized` exception.  There shouldn't be any Path Traversal vulnerabilities, and even if there were the website has nothing confidential in it so I'm happy to take the risk.